# Unity How to remove gameobject if they are on same line?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a game like 2 cars. And I have written code to create a instantiater. It is a car game and there are 4 lanes. Let me show you a picture of my game and yeah this is solely for practise.

[image]

Player should avoid square objects and eat circle objects but sometimes 2 square objects get spawned in a same lane making impossible for player to win. I have written this script to control that but I failed. Please help me. At least have a check to my DetectSameLaneFunction(). And tell me what I am doing wrong.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject[] objects;
    public float delaytime = 2f; // this is separate for each prefab with which script is attaches 
    public float spawnrate = 1f; // this is separate for each prefab with which script is attaches 

    public static int lastgameobjectindex;
    public static GameObject lastgameobject;
    public static GameObject SecondLastGameObject;
    private float loadingtime;
    private GameObject go; // just a temporary variable

    public static List<GameObject> spawnobjects = new List<GameObject>();
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        loadingtime = delaytime;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (Time.time > loadingtime)
        {
            float randomness = spawnrate * Time.deltaTime;
            if ( randomness < Random.value)
            {
                Spawners();
            }
            NextLoadTime();
        }
    }

   private  void Spawners()
    {
        int spawnnumber = Random.Range(0, 2);
        GameObject go = Instantiate(objects[spawnnumber]) as GameObject;
        go.transform.position = this.transform.position;
        spawnobjects.Add(go);
        Debug.Log(spawnobjects[spawnobjects.Count-1]);
        DetectSameLaneObjects();
      /*  if (spawnobjects.Count > 4)
        {
            spawnobjects.RemoveAt(0);
        }*/
    }

    private void  DetectSameLaneObjects()
    {
        if (spawnobjects.Count > 3)
        {
           lastgameobject = spawnobjects[spawnobjects.Count - 1];
            SecondLastGameObject = spawnobjects[spawnobjects.Count - 2];
             lastgameobjectindex = spawnobjects.Count - 1;
            if (SecondLastGameObject.transform.position.x != lastgameobject.transform.position.x
                )
            {
                if (Mathf.Abs(lastgameobject.transform.position.x- SecondLastGameObject.transform.position.x) < 2.3f)
                {

                    Debug.Log("Destroy function getting called");
                     Destroy(spawnobjects[lastgameobjectindex]);
                    spawnobjects.RemoveAt(lastgameobjectindex);

                }
            }
        }
    }
    void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(this.transform.position, 0.6f);
    }

    void NextLoadTime()
    {
        loadingtime = Time.time + delaytime;
    }

}
```

Comment: Generate a maximum of one item per line? Presumably the player won't be able to collect two round objects at once anyway?

Comment: @James delayrate and spawnrate are different for each gameobject. still it does not give solution. Can you provide me with some change in my script or new script

Comment: @James that's what I want to fix objects appearing twice in a lane

Comment: why not simply check the line besides it for a cube and if there is one, don't add the other cube? Simplify the problem from "Remove one elem if there are two at same height" to "only add one cube max per height"

Comment: Maybe don't generate two independently random numbers? `do { a = rand(); b = rand(); } while(a == 0 && b == 0);`